# US Passport damage (Back cover separating) - must I replace it?

Tags: passports, us-citizens

My US passport is slightly damaged:

[image: close up of passport damage]

Wondering if the small bends and slight separation along the top of the back cover will be an issue.

Comment: that looks pretty normal to me. mine was actually beginning to physically bend and i never got hassled about it

Answer (score 3):

It does not look like a damaged passport (at least just by looking at the picture). If you are still tentative about using it, I suggest you contact the nearest passport issuing centre. There are special passport fairs conducted across the United States. You may want to check one of the upcoming events.

Answer (score 2):

I had my front cover of my Indian passport completely separate out from the biographic page and I did not think that would ever be a problem. But then one evening while travelling from India to New York, I was being held at check in and my passport was taken inside for supervisor recommendation. Luckily I was given back my passport and was asked to visit the Indian embassy in NYC  for a new passport as soon as I land.

However, once i got back to NYC, I just used a glue stick to paste that cover to the biographic page and  never had any problem during 4 of my next international travels.

Comment: Some countries are rather strict about it. Sticking with glue can be considered tampering with. Please don't recommend it and try replacing the passport.

Comment: I am not recommending it. Just stating my experience. And I have replaced it now.

Comment: Im in similar situation to @BhushanKale, my H1B lottery application is going to go through in March, im holding off on reissuing passport until then , hope I dont face any issues.